OneSignal websdk angular error on init error with circular structure to JSON
this.oneSignal.init({
  appId: "1111111111111111",
  serviceWorkerPath: 'push/OneSignalSDKWorker.js',
  scope: '/push/'
}).then()

ERROR
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor '_ZoneImpl'
|     property '_zoneDelegate' -> object with constructor '_ZoneDelegate'
--- property '_zone' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify ()
at stringify (Utils.js:46:21)
at Array.map ()
at d.logMethodCall (OneSignalUtils.js:41:55)
at g (utils.js:51:12)
at Vi.enqueue (OperationCache.js:6:9)
at Qi. (ExecutorBase.js:91:32)
at Generator.next ()
at r (tslib.es6.js:118:58)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:339:158)
